# MySQL Root Password

Tags: mysql, contraseña

Hola al tratar de cambiar el **password** de **root** me aparece que este no cumple con los requisitos y cuando intento verificar cuales son los requisitos me dice que debo resetear el password lo cual no puedo por el problema anterior.

La forma en que entro es mediante **sudo mysql**, pasa lo mismo con **mysql -h localhost -u root -p**

```
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

---

Ya resolvi el problema, la sintaxis para cambiar el password es diferente.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS 'MyNewPass';
```

Comment: Claro, el mensaje de error te lo decía claramente: `You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement ...` Quizá conviene que pongas la solución como respuesta, de modo que pueda ser útil a futuros usuarios. Podrías incluir algún detalle de la documentación sobre `ALTER USER`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si aunque no resolvió el problema de privilegios con phpmyadmin, sin embargo encontré un recurso el día de hoy para la correcta instalación.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que encontré la solución para cambiar el password, no solucione los problemas con la integración de phpMyAdmin y MySQL. Agrego la liga de un pequeño tutorial que encontré para la correcta instalación de MySQL en nuevas versiones de linux.

[Como instalar MySQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Y si les aparece este error

> your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Solo deben agregar el siguiente codigo para verificar cuales son los requisitos del password.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```